# GHG emissions per company per year (carbon footprint database)

Tags: greenhouse-gas-emissions, emissions

Which countries require corporations to report their GHG emissions (eg tonnes of CO2 [or GWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_warming_potential) emitted), and where can I find those numbers per company?

I'm trying to find companies who do high-energy industrial manufacturing (eg steel production) with renewable energy power sources.

For example, [Salzgitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salzgitter) is a major steel producer in Germany that's investing in hydrogen-powered electric arc furnaces powered by wind. I'd like to find-out the amount of steel they produce per year and divide that by the GWP that their production produces each year, and then I'd like to compare that "climate damage per product unit produced" to other companies in the region (eg [thyssenkrupp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThyssenKrupp)).

Where can I find the actual GWP produced per company per year?

Comment: See also https://climate.ec.europa.eu/eu-action/climate-strategies-targets/progress-made-cutting-emissions/emissions-monitoring-reporting_en

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to find such companies, but if the reason is that you're planning to do stock investments, then in that case what you want to read is the annual report.

Most companies these days do report their GHG emissions in the annual report. But that's not the important information you want right now. You want their future plans. Steelmaking currently doesn't use hydrogen. What you want is not companies who manufacture steel using only hydrogen (since there are none, I think), but companies whose plans to manufacture steel using hydrogen are the fastest and most believable.

The HYBRIT project by SSAB in my understanding is the fastest and most believable plan today to create steel in massive scale using hydrogen. So I'd say SSAB is the company you want to invest into.

Even if you aren't planning to make stock investments, reading the annual reports just for the GHG emission information could be useful.